# Click event is not working in MAC OS Safari 13.05 using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, safari, webdriverwait

Click event is not working in MAC OS Safari 13.05 Selenium Using java (No error message). Same Code works fine in other browser.

Code attempt:

```
public class CMSMlogin_Safari {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        WebDriver driver = new SafariDriver();
        //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://letskodeit.teachable.com"); 
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//A[@class='navbar-link fedora-navbar-link'][text()='\n" + 
                "          Login\n" + 
                "        ']\n")).click();   
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To locate/click on an element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `elementToBeClickable` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@class='navbar-link fedora-navbar-link' and contains(., 'Login')]"))).sendKeys("public");
  ```